# Does Cauchy second limit theorem work both ways?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I have been told, that Cauchy second limit theorem doesn't always work both ways - if the limit of $n$th root of sequence exist it doesn't immediately mean the limit of $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is equal to nth root limit. Can you explain why? Show an example? Thank you a lot.

Comment: but if nth root is once 2 and once 4 thank limit doesnt exist, or i dont understand yor comment correctly?                     @mlainz can you help me more :D and thank you very much for fast responds

Comment: mmm Agree and deleted comment.

Comment: See also: [Are the limits $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\,$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\,$ equal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2322587) and [Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=l$ imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=l$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2045648)

Comment: thanks, didnt see it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n=(1/2)^{n^2}$ if $n$ even, and $(1/4)^{n^2}$ if $n$ odd. Then the $n$th root of $a_n$ is at most $(1/2)^n \to 0.$ But depending on parity of $n$, the limit as $n \to \infty$ of $a_{n+1}/a_n$ will be zero or positive infinity, so that $a_{n+1}/a_n$ doesn't converge.

When $n$ is even, $a_{n+1}/a_n=(1/4)^{n^2+2n+1}/(1/2)^{n^2}=(1/2)^{n^2}(1/4)^{2n+1} \to 0.$

When $n$ is odd, $a_{n+1}/a_n=(1/2)^{n^2+2n+1}/(1/4)^{n^2}=(2)^{n^2}(1/4)^{2n+1}
 \to \infty.$

Note-- previously forgot to use power $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$ on numerator $a_{n+1}.$

Comment: Just added explanation of different limits $0,\infty.$

Comment: mmm We have a *single* sequence $a_n.$ When $n$ is even, $n+1$ is odd, so in that case we do a(n+1) 0dd over a(n)even. Similarly when $n$ is odd,$n+1$ is even, so then we do a(n+1) even over a(n) odd.

Comment: i made some thinking, and you are right!!

Comment: Thank you very much, my previous respond was stupid, i was thinking that i can have selected sequence when n+1 and n are the same parity omg....but its 3.a.m. in here. Cant up vote yet.

Comment: @mmm Note I fixed a small error in explanation of even/odd cases for ratio. Same limits $0,\infty$ as before.

Comment: thanks, i see it