# Intermediate steps in showing that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}= \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to understand why $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}= \lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$.

I was given a solution, but it gives no further details than 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^n}{n!}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)}/(n+1)!}{n^n/n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n.$$

What happened between $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^n}{n!}}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)}/(n+1)!}{n^n/n!}$?

Comment: How can this be true?  If $n=2$, for instance, the left hand side  ($\sqrt 2$) is irrational and the right hand side is rational ($9/4$).

Comment: [This should be helpful for you](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287932/476484).

Comment: @kimchilover The identity in the title is just saying that both expressions approach the same limit, they don't have to be the same. For example $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n} \to 0$, but one expression is always rational, the other always irrational.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Happened before the edit.

Answer (score 5):

If $a_n>0$ and there exists limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, then
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$
You can check that it's true as follows:

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = g > 0$ then for every $\epsilon>0$, $\epsilon <g$ there exists $N$ such that for $n\ge N$:
$$ g-\epsilon \le \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le g+\epsilon $$
$$ (g-\epsilon)^{n-N} \le \frac{a_{N+1}}{a_N}\frac{a_{N+2}}{a_{N+1}}\dots\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} = \frac{a_n}{a_N} \le (g+\epsilon)^{n-N}$$
$$ \sqrt[n]{a_N (g-\epsilon)^{n-N}} \le \sqrt[n]{a_n} \le \sqrt[n]{a_N (g+\epsilon)^{n-N}} $$
$$ g-\epsilon \le \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n} \le g+\epsilon $$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, it means that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=g$.

If $g=0$ the proof is similar, but the lower bound is just $0$.

In your problem $a_n = \frac{n^n}{n!}$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking logs and using [Stolz-Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):
$$
\log\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\log n -(\log 1 + \cdots + \log n)}n =
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(n + 1)\log(n + 1) - n\log n - \log(n + 1) =
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\frac{n + 1}n = \log\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac 1n\right)^n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\frac{n}{{n!}^{1/n}}$. So $\log A=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n \log(\frac{n}{r})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n \log(\frac{1}{\frac{r}{n}})$.

So as $n\to \infty$, $\log A$ grows to $\int_{0}^{1} \log(\frac{1}{x})dx=1$, hence $A$ grows to $\exp(1)=e$.

And we know that $e=\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have via [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) that:
 $$n! \sim \bigg(\frac{n}{e}\bigg)^n \cdot \sqrt{2 \pi n}$$

By plugging this in, and noting that $(2\pi n)^{\frac{1}{2n}}$ converges to $1$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ we arrive at $\frac{n}{\frac{n}{e}} = e$ which is obviously equaly to the RHS limit. Hope this helps

Comment: The question is much more elementary than Stirling's formula.

Comment: I disagree, I've used Stirling extensively throughout highschool and my early undergrad years to bypass opaque and lengthy convergence tests. The proof of this approximation is comparable in difficulty with the one presented in the other answer. But hey, if you feel like showing the OP a different piece of knowledge warrants a downvote, then do what you gotta do

Comment: "The proof of this approximation is comparable in difficulty with the one presented in the other answer. " Really? Where can I find this proof?

Comment: Re "the other answer": Right now there are several other answers. My favorite is the one from Soumyadip Sarkar, it being it seems to me the most elementary, using nothing more than the approximation of an integral by a Riemann sum.