# Show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}= \frac{1}{e}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial, radicals

> Show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}\right\} = \frac{1}{e}$$

What I did is to let $U_n = \dfrac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$ and  $U_{n+1} = \dfrac{(n+1)!^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{n+1}$. Then

$$\frac{ U_{n+1} }{U_n } = \frac{\frac{(n+1)!^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{n+1}}{\frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}}$$

Next I just got stuck. Am I on the right track, or am I wrong doing this type of sequence?

Comment: One option is to use Stirling's Approximation and its (rather tight) error estimates. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn).

Comment: @Travis The basest version of Stirling (with no error control) yields the result.

Comment: @Did Surely if one uses an approximation to evaluate a limit one must use error bounds for that approximation to justify that the computation, no?

Comment: @Travis Actually no, due to the power $1/n$. Note that $n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n$ implies $(n!)^{1/n}\sim n/e$, that is, $(n!)^{1/n}/n\to e$.

Comment: @Travis Again, no, since $x_n\sim y_n$ (when $y_n\ne0$) means that $x_n/y_n\to1$, with no error bound whatsoever.

Comment: @Did Ah, I understand your meaning now, and yes, I agree.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $v_n = \frac{n!}{n^n } $ then $$ \frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n } =\frac{(n+1)! }{(n+1)^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{n^n }{n!} =\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n }=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\to \frac{1}{e}$$ hence $$\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!} }{n} =\sqrt[n]{v_n} \to\frac{1}{e} .$$

Comment: I approve of this. +1

Comment: how does (n+1)! and n! vanish.?

Comment: @sam $$(n+1)n! = (n+1)!$$

Comment: Yes..there should be (n+1) in the numerator I suppose....!!!when applying infinity it should go to infinit..Am i right?

Comment: @sam but the $(n+1)$ in the numerator reduces the power by one in the denominator(which yeilds his last equality before taking the lim). It is quite a nice trick which my old eyes didn't see when I first saw this question.

Comment: Yep..You are right..

Answer (score 4):

As Travis suggested, consider $$A=\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}$$  Now, use Stirling approximation $$n!= \sqrt{2\pi n}\,\Big(\frac n e\Big)^n \Big(1+\frac 1 {12n}+\cdots\Big)$$ So $$A=(2\pi n)^{\frac 1 {2n}}\, \Big(1+\frac 1 {12n}+\cdots\Big)^{\frac 1 n} \frac 1e$$ The first two terms tends to $1$ when $n$ becomes large and then the limit.

Pushing the developments, you could arrive, for large values of $n$, to $$A\approx \frac{1}{e}+\frac{\log (2 \pi n)}{2\, e
  \, n}+\cdots$$

If you do not use to practice Stirling approximation, try to remember it; it is extremely useful every time you have to find the limit or the asymptotics of any function containing factorials.

Comment: Several times now, you posted an answer based on some very precise expansions. When the last terms of the expansion are unneeded to reach the result asked for by the OP, the fact should be mentioned. Here the $1/(12n)$ is not necessary, only the equivalent is (and actually even the $\sqrt{2\pi n}$ prefactor in Stirling is unnecessary, but this becomes more subtle).