# Determine if the following sequence is convergent and find its limit: $x_n=(n^n/n!)^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

Let we have the following sequence $$x_n=\left(\frac{n^n}{n!}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ Determine if  the following sequence is convergent  and find its limit

Comment: It converges to $e$, to shhow it you can use stirlings approximation.

Comment: @user109899 how can I do that ?

Comment: This is the same limit as here: [Finding the limit of $\frac {n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn). (You just use $(n^n)^{1/n}=n$ in the numerator.) It seems to be asked [quite often](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/28476).

Answer (score 1):

For convergence you can use the bounds
$$\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)^n\leq n!\leq\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$$
They are provable by induction (for $n\geq 6$ or sth like that).

If you want the limit, you'll probably have to use a version of the deeper result:
$$\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}\longrightarrow 1$$
( = Stirling's formula)

Comment: Why does your inequality show convergence?

Comment: By itself it doesn't, but it's a way to start if you're interested in convergence  only.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the $\log$ gives

$$\tag 1\frac{1}{n}(n\ln n -\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln k) = \ln n -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln k.$$

Because $\ln x$ is increasing and nonnegative on $[1,\infty),$ we have

$$\tag 2\int_1^n \ln x\ dx \le \sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln k \le \int_1^n \ln x\ dx +\ln(n+1).$$

Integrating by parts gives $\int_1^n \ln x\ dx = n\ln n - n + 1.$ It's now easy to see limit of $(1)$ equals $1,$ hence the limit of the original expression is $e.$