# How to solve this question related to limits of successions?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, factorial, radicals

I've done these two proves:

$\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\right)_{n}\rightarrow \frac{1}{e}$

$\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}-1 \right)_{n} \rightarrow 0$

And now I've to prove this statement, using the previous statements if are necessary:

$\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} \right)_{n}^{n}\rightarrow e$

All I could done to solve the limit is transformate the expression in this way:
$e^{lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\right)}$
and theoretically the limit of the exponent has to be 1, but I dont't know how to continue to prove it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean $(a)_{n}=a(a+1)(a+2)\times \ldots \times (a+n-1)$?

Comment: @NgChungTak No; $a_{n} := \left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\right)^{n} $

Comment: Avoid ambiguity: $$\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\right)_{\color{red}{n}}\rightarrow \frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: See [Finding the limit of $\frac {n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28476) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/28476).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Alternatively*, by (a weak) [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\ln n!=n\ln n-n+O(\ln n)
$$ one may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} \right)^{n}&=\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{n+1}\times\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{(n+1)!}} \right)^{n}
\\\\&=(n+1)\times ((n+1)!)^{-\frac1{n+1}}
\\\\&=e^{\ln(n+1)}\times e^{\large-\frac{\ln[(n+1)!]}{n+1}}
\\\\&=e^{\ln(n+1)}\times e^{\large-\ln(n+1)+1+O\big(\frac{\ln n}n\big)}
\\\\&=e\times e^{O\big(\frac{\ln n}n\big)}
\\\\& \to e
\end{align}
$$
as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but at the moment I can't use Stirling's aproximation as a tool to solve limits of successions.

Comment: Observe that, as $n \to \infty$, $\ln\left(n!\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n{\ln\left(k\right)} \sim \int_1^n{\ln\left(x\right)\, dx} = \left[ x\ln\left(x\right) - x \right]_1^n = n\ln\left(n\right) - n + 1$ is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks again! But I have not yet given differential or integral calculus in my real analysis class. So I can only use basic tools of successions to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to show that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}-\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=0.$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=\frac1e$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}-\frac{n+1}{n}\right)&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(n+1)\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{n+1}}{n\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}}-\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{n+1}}{\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}}-1\right)\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$　\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}＝1+\frac{1}{n}＋o(\frac1{n}).　$$
So
$$　\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\right)^n＝\left(1+\frac1{n}+o(\frac1{n})\right)^n.　$$
Therefore
$$　\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\right)^n＝e.　$$

Comment: I think there is a subtle flaw here. You have only proved that $$\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}＝1+\frac{1}{n}＋o(1)$$ and not $$\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}＝1+\frac{1}{n}＋o(\frac1{n})$$

Answer (score 1):

$\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} \right)^{n}=\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!^{n}}}{n!}=\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{(n+1)!^{n}}{n!^{n+1}}}=\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n!}}$

We know that if $lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}} $ exists, then $lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_{n}}=lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}} $

So, applying this to $a_{n}:=\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n!}$ we obtained:

$\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n!} \frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}}=\frac{n+1}{n}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n-1}=\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} \rightarrow e$

Comment: Very good approach +1