# Ask for a proof of an inequality bounding the ratio of two consecutive geometric means of the first finitely many natural numbers

Tags: inequality, asymptotics, special-functions, factorial, gamma-function

A colleague asked me the first one of the following problems:

- For $n\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$, is the inequality
  \begin{equation}
  \frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}>1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\ln\sqrt{2n\pi}\,}{n^2}-\frac{5}{12n^3}\label{1}\tag{1}
  \end{equation}
  valid?
- If the inequality \eqref{1} is valid, can one find the best constants $\alpha>5$ and $\beta\le5$ such that the double inequality
  \begin{equation}
  1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\ln\sqrt{2n\pi}\,}{n^2}-\frac{\alpha}{12n^3}>\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}>1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\ln\sqrt{2n\pi}\,}{n^2}-\frac{\beta}{12n^3}, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}\label{2}\tag{2}
  \end{equation}
  is valid?

Notice that $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$, where
$$
\Gamma(z)= \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t} \textrm{d}t, \quad \Re(z)>0
$$
is the classical Euler gamma function.

To the best of my knowledge, in the papers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] below, some properties, including increasing property, inequalities, and (logarithmicaly) complete monotonicity, of the functions
\begin{align}
&\frac{[{\Gamma(x+\alpha+1)}]^{1/(x+\alpha)}}{[{\Gamma(x+1)}]^{1/x}}, &
&\frac{[\Gamma(x+1)]^{1/x}}{[\Gamma(x+1+\beta)]^{1/(x+\beta)}}\biggl(1+\frac{\beta}{x}\biggr)^\alpha, \\
&\frac{[\Gamma(x+1)]^{1/x}}{[\Gamma(x+1+\beta)]^{1/(x+\beta)}}\biggl(1+\frac{\beta}{x+1}\biggr)^\alpha,& 
&\frac{[\Gamma(x+a+1)]^{1/(x+a)}}{[\Gamma(x+b+1)]^{1/(x+b)}}
\end{align}
were investigated. These results may be useful for answering the above two questions.

References

1. H. Alzer and C. Berg, *Some classes of completely monotonic functions, II*, Ramanujan J. **11** (2006), no. 2, 225--248; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s11139-006-6510-5.
2. Chao-Ping Chen and Feng Qi, *Monotonicity results for the gamma function*, Journal of Inequalities in Pure and Applied Mathematics **4** (2003), no. 2, Article 44; available online at http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/article282.html.
3. Feng Qi and Chao-Ping Chen, *Monotonicity and convexity results for functions involving the gamma function*, International Journal of Applied Mathematical Sciences **1** (2004), no. 1, 27--36.
4. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *Some logarithmically completely monotonic functions related to the gamma function*, Journal of the Korean Mathematical Society **47** (2010), no. 6, 1283--1297; available online at https://doi.org/10.4134/JKMS.2010.47.6.1283.
5. J. Sandor, *Sur la fonction gamma*, Publ. C.R.M.P. Neuchatel, Serie I, **21** (1989), 4--7.

Comment: Some inspiration on a related problem can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045517/how-to-solve-this-question-related-to-limits-of-successions?noredirect=1