# how to solve $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (\log x!/x \log x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, problem-solving

It will be appreciated if you help me to solve this limit : 
I'm wondering if you desribe steps of solving

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log x!}{x \log x}$$

edit: i'm computer engineering student and i need to solve this limit that i've faced with it in "Data mining" course and "decision trees"

edit: 
(1 - log(x))/(log(1/x)) + (1/2 - (log(2 pi))/(2 log(1/x)))/x + O((1/x)^(3/2))

(Puiseux series)

Comment: what kind of $\log$ is this?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The answer is independent of the base of the logarithm.

Comment: Anyway, [at this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n) you can see the steps to show that the limit is $1$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

*Stirling's formula* and *equivalents*. You should find $1$.