# Prove: $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}\right)=\frac{1}{e}$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial, radicals

> Prove: $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}\right)=\frac{1}{e}$

I tried to do some algebraic manipulations and squeeze it but couldn't get further.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: use stirling's approximations.

Comment: See [Finding the limit of $\frac {n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28476) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/28476).