# Examine convergence of $ \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{n!(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{n^2}}{n^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I need to examine convergence of the following sum:

$$\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{n!(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{n^2}}{n^n}$$

I know that:
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n!(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{n^2}}{n^n} = 0$$

And that all elements of sequence $a_n$ are positive. Therefore I can use Cauchy's root test:
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{n^2}}{n^n}}= \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{n}}{n}$$
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{n}}{n}}= \frac{\sqrt[n^2]{n!}(1+\frac{1}{2n})}{\sqrt[n]{n}}$$

But it gives me noting since I don't know what happens to $\sqrt[n^2]{n!}$ when $n \to \infty$. I tried also d'alembert's ratio test, but it gives me nothing. I think it may be LTC on limits.

Comment: [Stirling's Formula](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%AF%E7%89%B9%E9%9D%88%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%8F) estimates $n!$ in terms of $n^n$. What I am curious is that I don't recall Cauchy's criterion be using root tests. Are there references for that?

Comment: Oh, it's called 'root test' in English, I'm sorry. Unfortunately, I can't use Stirling's Formula, Taylor's series nor l'Hospital.

Comment: In fact the second root test is well, invalid as that is not how that works. You only do once.

Comment: I think I can do it twice (as every other of those basic tests). THe problem is, every time I use it, it "cuts" some of the information comming from original sequence.

Comment: In this case, it's a *big* cut: the second limit is 1 (inconclusive), and the first is not (see the answer).

Comment: So, you say that I can't do the same test more than once? What about merging other ones together?

Comment: Consider $$a_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$$ the root test will give you $1/2$, *but* if you apply this value to the root test again, you will get $1$. The problem is that, you are in fact doing the root test to the sequence $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ on the so-called second root test, not the original sequence.

Comment: And well, you can always refer to other tests if the test you used is inconclusive.

Comment: Yeah, but it seams a bit tricky to me. You gave me an example that shows that it's not always correct to use root test twice. But (if you know) I would like to find out if it is *always* a bad idea (does it work in any case at all?). And if it does / doesn't, what about other tets? Is it ok to merge other tests with each other, or if I calculate my limit once with one test I shouldn't ever do that again? As I suppose it's not that easy and depends on particular cases, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Hmm, well it depends on a lot of a different cases, sorry if I can't answer that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}(1+\frac{1}{2n})^{n}}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n} \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{n}$$
To justify the split of limit, you should note that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{n}$$
is a common limit (and I'm sure you can find it). For the first limit, refer to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn).

Comment: So it's root test $\to$ common limits (that first one is less common I would say) $\to$ proof of convergence?

Comment: @mathp You're correct.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method. First note that
$$
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{2n}}} \right)^{n^2 }  = \left( {\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{2n}}} \right)^{2n} } \right)^{n/2}  < e^{n/2} 
$$
for all $n\geq 1$. Second,
\begin{align*}
\log n! & = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\log k}  = \log n + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\log k}  < \log n + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\int_k^{k + 1} {\log tdt} } \\ & = \log n + \int_1^n {\log tdt}  = (n + 1)\log n - n + 1.
\end{align*}
Thus
$$
n! < en\frac{{n^n }}{{e^n }} \Rightarrow \frac{{n!}}{{n^n }}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{2n}}} \right)^{n^2 }  < ene^{ - n/2} .
$$
But
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {ne^{ - n/2} }  = \frac{{\sqrt e }}{{(\sqrt e  - 1)^2 }} \approx 3.9
$$
converges, so does the original series.

Answer (score 0):

Since $n!^{1/n} \approx n/e$, the n-th root is about

$(n/e)(1+1/(2n))^n/n
\approx e^{1/2}/e
= e^{-1/2}<1$

so the sum converges.