# Exist or Not ? $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x-k}$, $1 \leq k \leq x-1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, products

I was trying to evaluate
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\dfrac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{n}}
$$
without resorting to a certain theorem that states :
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\; a_n\,^{\frac{\Large 1}{\Large n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right).
$$

**With my own idea:**

- By using the discreet definition of factorial using the product notation (also converting $n^n$ into discreet product) :

$$
n! = \prod_{0\leq k \leq n-1} (n-k)= n\cdot\left(\prod_{1\leq k \leq n-1} (n-k)\right)
$$

$$
n^n = \prod_{1\leq k \leq n} n = n\cdot\left(\prod_{1\leq k \leq n-1} n \right)
$$

And by dividing $n-k$ by $n$ and duplicating the limit (one for evaluating the limit inside product notation and another for reminding myself that $x$ goes to $\infty$ ) into two I get this limit :

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{1\leq k \leq n-1} \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{n}}$ **(1)**

Evaluating the inner limit by logarithm and L'Hopital get me into this point :

$a =  \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1}{n-k}$, $1 < k < n-1$

where $y =  \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{n}}$, and $a = \ln(y)$

My Question :

$1$) Does $a$ exist as $k$ varies and goes to $n-1$ ? (Continue to Q$2$)

$2$) How to evaluate it ? (Continuation of Q$1$)

$3$) Is my way of doing the limit at equation **(1)** valid (Duplicating the limit) ??

$4$) Any other way to do $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\dfrac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{n}}$ without that sequence theorem I mentioned earlier

My opinion about Q$1$ : because the main limit (at the very beginning) exist and has a value, I think somehow $a$ exist, but what confuse me is that $a$ varies between $0$ and $-1$ ($a = -1$ when $k$ goes to $n-1$).

Q$2$ : I don't have any idea as $k$ value is varying (at least I know that when $k$ is small then $a$ goes to $0$, and when $k$ value is approaching $n-1$ then $a$ goes to $-1$)

Comment: 1. $a = 0$ for any fixed $k$, but you can not vary it, because it means $k$ depends on $n$, and it changes the limit.

Comment: You can't have two nested $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ since the first one already binds the variable $n$. Why do you think you need two limits?

Comment: @Christoph The 1 is a typo, the inequality is just my way of writing that $k$ goes from 1 to $n-1$

Comment: I think i need two limits because the upper bound is a variable

Comment: Well, you don't.

Comment: Your duplication of the limit is not correct — you get that the limit is 1, but it is $e^{-1}$.

Comment: Any other solution beside mine and **Without the sequence theorem with the supremum** is appreciated (for Q4)

Comment: Strangely by some subtitution to change the inner limit ( by replacing $-\dfrac{k}{n}$ with subtitution), i was able to change the inner limit to equal 1, and then because $x$ goes to $\infty$  i can just do $1 = 1+\dfrac{1}{x}$ inside the product notation to get into the correct answer : $\dfrac{1}{e}$)

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn

Comment: @Gary ah i overlooked that second answer, thanks for that.

Comment: @Gary but i think that's kind of circular logic, because what if i dont know the value of the limit yet ??

Comment: @JamboRambo No, you seem to misunderstood something.

Comment: @Gary of what ?

Comment: @JamboRambo You only need to know that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to e$ which is a basic fact (defintion).

Comment: I know that, what i meant by circular logic is that by using the limit definition of $e$ then that mean i would have known before that the limit value involve some multiple/power of e . There was an answer that was wrong earlier but he didn't use circular logic because he didn't know that the value of the limit is $\dfrac{1}{e}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:
$$ {n!\over n^n} = \prod_{k=1}^n {k\over n}$$
$$ \ln \left({n!\over n^n}\right)^{1/n} = \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \ln{k\over n}$$
It can be noticed that it is a Riemann integral sum:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \ln{k\over n} = \int_0^1\ln x\,dx = (x\ln x-x)|_0^1 = -1 $$
We have $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln \left({n!\over n^n}\right)^{1/n} = -1$$
so $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left({n!\over n^n}\right)^{1/n} = e^{-1}$$

Comment: Oh that was good, i didn't think of Riemann Summ.

Answer (score 1):

Quick approach - Sterling's formula:

$(\frac{n!}{n^n})^\frac{1}{n}\approx \frac{1}{e}(\sqrt{2\pi n})^\frac{1}{n}\to \frac{1}{e}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\ln \left( \frac {n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}=\frac {1}{n}\ln (n!)-\ln n.$

For $n\ge 2$ we can obtain crude but useful lower & upper estimates for $\ln (n!)$ as follows: $$(n\ln n)-n+1=\int_1^n\ln x\,dx=$$ $$=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\int_j^{j+1}\ln x\,dx<$$ $$<\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\int_j^{j+1}\ln (j+1)\,dx=$$ $$=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\ln (j+1)=\ln (n!).$$ ......and............ $$\ln (n!)=\sum_{j=1}^n\ln j=$$ $$=\sum_{j=1}^n\int_j^{j+1} \ln j\,dx<$$ $$<\sum_{j=1}^n\int_j^{j+1} \ln (x+1)\,dx=$$ $$=\int_1^n\ln (x+1)\,dx=$$ $$=(n+1)\ln (n+1)-n+1-2\ln 2.$$

From this, and from $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {\ln (n+1)}{n}=0$ we immediately   obtain $\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln \left( \frac {n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}=-1.$

Stirling's Formula  $n!(1-\frac {1}{6n})<S(n)<n!(1+\frac {1}{6n})$ for $n>0,$ where $S(n)=(\frac {n}{e})^n \sqrt {2\pi n}$, is more difficult to prove and provides much more precision than is needed for your Q.